# Error: Main method not found in class using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I get the following error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class model.JNIResultSet, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I use JNI to access method from java in C but the main method is missing.

This code works for me:

```
public class JNIResultSet {

    public JNIResultSet() { }

    public native static model.Spieler[] getSpieler();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("spieler");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spieler s[] = getSpieler();
        for (Spieler sp : s) {
            AddSpieler(sp);
        }
        // insert empty row at the bottom
        AddSpieler(new Spieler("","",0));

        SharedTable t = new SharedTable();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The problem is, that I want to put the main into a separate class.
`Main.java` looks like that:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spieler s[] = JNIResultSet.getSpieler();
        for (Spieler sp : s) {
            JNIResultSet.AddSpieler(sp);
        }
        // insert empty row at the bottom
        JNIResultSet.AddSpieler(new Spieler("","",0));

        SharedTable t = new SharedTable();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Do you know how to fix the problem with the main?
I just want to have my `main` in a other class.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you launch your program?

Comment: do you launch the `Main` class ? using `java -cp ... my.package.Main` ?

Comment: Oh thanks guys, I launched the program wrong